# Adding scrollbars to browser window when a div overflows

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

Before I tell about my problem, let me say that I am a beginner in web development. I am currently working on a webpage, which gets items from a database, then use JavaScript to dynamically display them. For this purpose, I use divs.

I have a main div, which contains several other, smaller ones. They appear the way I want, the problem starts when I resize the window: the div simply "overflows" - some parts of it don't appear in the resized browser. There are no scrollbars either, so I can't scroll to them.

I tried to search the net (including this site) but I haven't found anything useful - most likely because I haven't used the correct expressions.

Here is my code:

```
function TableDraw(){
    //I create the main div here:
    var maindiv = document.createElement('div');
    maindiv.style.position = "absolute";
    maindiv.style.marginLeft = "280px";
    maindiv.style.width = "auto";
    maindiv.style.top = "0px";
    maindiv.style.bottom ="0px";
    maindiv.style.overflow="auto";


    //A variable to help me position the rows of divs
    var rowcounter = 0;

    //Here, I create 3x5 divs; (currently) each one is the same size
    //If it's the 1st row (index 0), I append an image to them.
    //If it's the 2nd or the 3rd, I set their background color to red
    //for debugging (so I can see them).
    for (var k=0; k<3; k++){
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
            newdiv.style.position = "fixed";
            newdiv.style.marginLeft =((i)*120) +"px";
            newdiv.style.top = 10 + (rowcounter*125) + "px";
            newdiv.id = "div" + i;
            newdiv.style.height = "125px";
            newdiv.style.width = "100px";
            newdiv.style.border ="thin solid";


            if(k==0){
                var img = document.createElement('img');
                img.src = "/images/troops/" + (i+1) + ".png";
                img.style.width = "100px";
                img.style.height = "125px";
                newdiv.appendChild(img);
            } else {
                newdiv.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            }
            maindiv.appendChild(newdiv);
        }
        rowcounter++;
    }

    //This is almost the same as the previous, but it only has 4 columns.
    for (var k=0; k<3; k++){
        for (var i=0; i<4; i++){
            var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
            newdiv.style.position = "fixed";
            newdiv.style.marginLeft = ((i)*120) +"px";
            newdiv.style.top = 10 + (rowcounter*125) + "px";
            newdiv.id = "div" + i;
            newdiv.style.height = "125px";
            newdiv.style.width = "100px";
            newdiv.style.border ="thin solid";

            if(k==0){
                var img = document.createElement('img');
                img.src = "/images/troops/" + (i+6) + ".png";
                img.style.width = "100px";
                img.style.height = "125px";
                newdiv.appendChild(img);
            } else {
                newdiv.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            }
            maindiv.appendChild(newdiv);
        }
        rowcounter++;
    }
    document.body.appendChild(maindiv);
}
```

And you can check the current state of the site: [demo](http://clashofclans-hungary.netau.net/forstacko.php).

If I'd have to guess, the problem is with the "absolute" and "fixed" positions.

I already tried to add scrollbars, but the most I was able to manage was scrollbars in the divs, and no scrollbar at the side of the window. The only way to get those is to resize the window so only the 3 buttons on the left side (created with JS, too) visible, then, the bars appear.

Is there any way to add bars to the window, so I can scroll to the "overflowing" div parts?

Thank you for your help in advance!

(And sorry if my code is horrible)

Comment: Have you heard of `overflow: scroll` ?

Comment: Remove your position:fixed or absolute. That is step 1...

Comment: @AkshaySharma yes, I even tried to use it, but it did not work - I added it it to the maindiv.

Answer (score 0):

There are some fundamental issues with the CSS and plan, but I can see you have the right idea but the wrong implementation. Instead look at either using `float:left` to hvae the in-line elements or have a css class to manage it using `display: inline` or similar. There are lots of solutions online to getting the layout you want, but using fixed and absolute position isn't the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute or fixed positioned divs dont affect the height of the parent containing element (in your case I think this is the body element). Try using relative positioning and float rules. You might also want to google "clearfix" to force height on divs containing floated elements. Not the best solution but another option would be to calculate the height of the body/containing element based on its contents and set it using JS.